# zookeeper server expiring session timeout exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm beginner using Kafka and druid. Recently I get an error when I upload data to druid at the parse data step. I don't know about this issue and error. I have assumed that this zookeeper of the Kafka server getting errors. I ran the zookeeper by following `./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` but the result has timed out like the picture

[image]

Comment: You need to provide full log to see if there is an error or not?

Comment: Are you expecting Zookeeper to start in the background and return you to an input prompt? It doesn't... Those messages are INFO, not "timeout errors"... You need to start a new terminal session or use systemctl to start Zookeeper as a background service

Comment: I had a similar error when my connection string to postgresql was incorrect and did not therefore resolve